# Story about gentiles hanging to a Jewish person's clothes when the kingdom is rebuilt

Tags: gentiles, messiah, judaism

I remember hearing a story that says that when the Messiah comes and the kingdom is reinstated, it's not only Jewish people that will live in the kingdom, but also gentiles, and that the gentiles will enter the kingdom by hanging to the Jewish people's clothes. I remember it saying that 7 gentiles would hang on to one Jewish person's clothes.

Does it ring any bell as to where this comes from ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're referring to [Zechariah 8:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Zechariah.8.22-23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi):

> "The many peoples and the multitude of nations shall come to seek the LORD of Hosts in Jerusalem and to entreat the favor of the Lord.
> Thus said the LORD of Hosts: In those days, ten men from nations of every tongue will take hold—they will take hold of every Jew by a corner of his cloak and say, “Let us go with you, for we have heard that God is with you.”"

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you.

Comment: @JoshuaPath you're very welcome. And welcome to the site.